# Removing characters from grep output

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I've been whittling down my grep output (which comes down to a listing of numbers that I intend to associate with other fields.)  My problem is that numbers above 999 have commas in them, and I'm wondering how to print the output with out the commas.

so instead of the output being:

```
1,200,300
```

it would just be:

```
1200300
```

Any suggestions for an additional pipe command that I could add?

Thanks

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Try this

```
< your command > | tr -d ','
```

tr will remove all commas

Comment: According to google code search this is a much less frequently used feature!

Comment: Using this with a word will remove each of the characters, not the word.

Comment: how can we remove chars only if a line begins with those chars?

Comment: @AlexanderMills add a grep before to check if the line begins with a set of characters or not

Answer (score 26):

```
 < your command > | sed -e 's/,//g'
```

This will replace all commas with "nothing" without changing anything else.

Answer (score 1):

instead of grep use a single awk command like below

```
awk '/your pattern/{gsub(",","");print}' your_file
```